# Matlab .m files, based on GUI, not rendering properly

Tags: matlab, rendering, matlab-guide

I am working on MATLAB R2013a. Everything works fine except for some .m files which have a GUI component. When I run these files the GUI window doesn't pop up. It shows on my taskbar, but when I click on it, it just doesn't pop up.

In another instance (a different .m file) the GUI pops up, but doesn't align properly on the screen. 1/4 th of it is outside the screen and when I try to pull it down, it just wouldn't work. It doesn't re-size/restore so I can't align it that way either.

I was using Windows 8 earlier, so I thought that might be a problem. Because these .m files work fine on my friends' computer, which had Windows 7. Then I installed Win 7 on my laptop, but the problem still persists.

I changed the Matlab verison to no avail. Please help!

Comment: What are the `Units` and `Position` properties of the main figure window? If you built this in GUIDE you can see (in GUIDE) by double clicking anywhere on the figure window (not one of the subcomponents) to open the property manager. I suspect the `XY` positioning was set using `pixels` or `characters` on one machine and now it's offscreen on the other.

Comment: Try putting `movegui(handles.mainfigurewindowhandlehere, 'center')` in your `OpeningFcn`

Comment: @excaza Units is character and Position is [60,5,240.0,80.077]

Comment: Also, why would the use of characters create this problem? Characters are of the same length in both machines

Comment: It may just be a personal thing but I think MathWorks' decision to use a non-standard unit as the default is really stupid. The size varies for sure by OS; GUIs I've made in Windows using `characters` are completely broken visually on OSX, for instance. I would adjust to `pixels` or `normalized`, depending on your preference, and see if that fixes your issue. It probably wouldn't hurt to keep the [`movegui`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movegui.html) call in your `OpeningFcn`, I use it for all my GUIs.

Comment: Cool! As a note, it appears that the default unit was changed to `pixels` at some point. Not sure which release it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, check the `Units` and `Position` properties of your main figure window. If built in GUIDE, you can do this in the GUIDE interface by double clicking anywhere on the figure window (not one of the subcomponents) to open the property manager. You can also check this programmatically by inserting a [breakpoint](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) in your code and using the `get()` command with your main figure handle (or [the dot notation if you have 2014b and newer](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2014/10/14/matlab-r2014b-graphics-part-2-using-graphics-objects/)).

Though the default `Units` figure property is `pixels` in R2014b, in older versions (I don't know when it switched, but I'm glad they did) the default is `characters` which, from [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html), are:

> Character units are determined by the default system font. Each
>   character unit is the width of the letter x. The height of each
>   character unit is the distance between the baselines of two lines of
>   text.

Because they're determined by your default system font these could vary between Windows installs and definitely vary between OSes (like OSX), causing pretty significant (and frustrating) compatibility issues. The best thing to do would be to change the `Units` property for all of your components to a uniform unit. The most common ones I've seen used are `pixels` or `normalized`; there is no 'right' answer so play around with them to see which you'd prefer to use for a given context. Fortunately, if you change these in GUIDE they (should) be converted automatically to retain the layout in the construction interface.

Another useful function is [`movegui()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movegui.html), which allows you to set the position of a figure using either a string or a position vector. Assuming your figure is smaller than the screen resolution, placing `movegui(handles.mainfigurewindowhandlehere, 'onscreen')` into your `OpeningFcn` should get it back on screen for you. See the documentation for other arguments. I generally include a call to this function in every GUI I make, whether it's built programmatically or in GUIDE.